# The experiment of passing a variable to a stream

Tags: powershell, runspace

I want to understand how flows communicate with each other. More precisely, when a new thread is born and a variable is passed to it, then this is a common variable or a synchronized copy.

Here is what I do to figure it out:

```
$A = '0'

# Expansion of the variable to 32 MB (2^25 characters)
(1..25).ForEach{ $A += $A -join '' }

$A
$A.Length

# Torment further. Writing a variable to a table
$B = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{ Name = $A })

Clear-Variable A
Remove-Variable A

$B

Write-host "Oh, that wasn't easy. Owner, maybe enough?"

# But no, not enough. Now you pass B to another thread

$RunSpace = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$RunSpace.Open()
$RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('B', $B )
$PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({})
$PowerShell.Runspace = $RunSpace

$Null = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

# Here I do not close the threads for clarity
```

This is what I saw on the Memory graph:

[image]

I realized that I use a synchronized copy of $B hashtable, not one table. But what if there are a lot of such large tables and a lot of threads? Am I hopelessly getting a total waste of memory?

**Am I really forced to create copies of the same $B hashtable for each thread? Can't I create one common $B hashtable for all threads?**

**Edit.** I decided to raise the stakes and made `1..30` instead of `1..25` (2 to the power of 30, which is **$A ≡ 1GB (!!!)** ). And what did I see? The first and second steps were added by 1GB. That is, another 1GB table was transferred to the stream. As a result, I got 2GB!

Just look at that:

[image]

Comment: Runspaces share memory, so you can pass same variable from the main thread to runspaces. Thread itself uses about 2MB of memory, it's probably what you see on the second bump.

Comment: I want to believe in it. However, @Mike Twc please look the edited post. I increased the size of the variable to 1GB and I got 2 GB in total ($A plus $B). How is this possible if the hashtable is shared (it is 1 GB in size)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd think this just creates a copy of that variable:

`$RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('B', $B )`

You need to pass it as parameter. Below is an example

```
$LargeVar = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\temp\SomeLargeFile.zip")

$work = { param($SharedVar)

   $threadId = [System.AppDomain]::GetCurrentThreadId()
   Write-Output "Thread $threadId : result $($SharedVar.count)"    
}

$workParams = @{SharedVar = $LargeVar}

$rs1 = [powershell]::Create()
$rs2 = [powershell]::Create()
$rs3 = [powershell]::Create()

foreach($rs in $rs1, $rs2, $rs3) {

   $rs.AddScript($work).AddParameters($workParams).Invoke()
   $rs.Commands.Clear() 

}
```

If you are going to invoke runspaces in parallel, you probably need to create concurrent collection and exchange data between runspaces using it.

Comment: thank you. What if I change the hash table in the child stream? As far as I understand (if passed as a parameter), I can’t get the change in the parent thread.